# Granting EXEC permission to user: cannot find the object

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am logged in my database with a db_owner account. I am trying to grant EXEC permission to another user: **MyTestUser**. The simple code is:

```
USE MyDB
GO

GRANT EXEC ON [MyTestUser] TO PUBLIC
```

The error:

> Cannot find the object 'MyTestUser', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

You don't see it in the following picture cause for the sake of privacy but trust me it's there, exactly as **MyTestUser**

Comment: not sure , but I think to see the users you need server level permission and your db_owner account doesn't have that , you  might find out more about that

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have mixed up your statement.  A `GRANT` statement usually goes like this:

`GRANT` <permission> `ON` <what resource you want to grant access to> `TO` <who you want to get the access to the resource>

So your statement is saying you want PUBLIC (all users) to have rights to run `EXEC` statements on `MyTestUser`.  It is expecting `MyTestUser` to be a function, stored procedure, etc.  So if that is a user, it would fail because it can't find something executable called "MyTestUser".

Say you wanted allow to MyTestUser to execute `dbo.spMySproc`, you would run:

```
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.spMySProc TO MyTestUser
```